# System.loadLibrary cannot find the library

Tags: java, opencv, javacv, opencv3.0

i do not why eclipse underscore the `System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);` with red line and says :`native library name can't resolved to a variable`

the opencv2.4.11 libs are imported successfully so that such code `Mat imgSrc = new Mat();` is recognizable.

**code**

```
public class Core {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

        Mat imgSrc = new Mat();
        imgSrc = Highgui.imread("c:/private/ArbeitsOrdner_19_Mar_2015/images/images.jpg");

        System.out.println("channels: " + imgSrc.channels());
    }
}
```

Comment: What value is `Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME`?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi sorry i didnt get it?

Comment: Read the **very first** operation your `main` method calls. You're obviously passing a value, so what value is passed to `System.loadLibrary`?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi i do not know it, in a any opencv turorial with java it is always like this

Comment: Then print out the value on screen and see if the file (dll) exists on the path it displays.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi now i solved it using: org.opencv.core.Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. :-)